# What Mathematical Technique is used to compare algorithm complexity?

Tags: algorithm, math

I started reading 'Introduction to Algorithms' today, but I've gotten a bit confused over one of the exercises.

Exercise 1.2.2 asks the reader

> Suppose we are comparing implementations of Merge sort and Insertion Sort on the same
>   machine. For inputs of size n, insertion sort runs in 8n^2 steps, 
>   while merge sort runs in 64n log n steps.
>
> For which values of n does insertion sort beat merge sort?

I first tried opening up Wolfram Alpha and using it to draw graphs of the equations, but I couldn't accurately compare the two graphs.

I then tried choosing a random value for n (200), working out the equations on paper, and then modifying the value of n based on my results.
But that took too long.

What is the correct way to solve this exercise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8n%5E2%3D64n+log_2+n): 8*n*<sup>2</sup> = 64*n* log<sub>2</sub> *n*. Just put both things in a single equation.

I.e., roughly *n* = 43 is the limit of insertion sort's usefulness here.

Usually you would solve this by solving above equation *f*(*n*) = *g*(*n*) by solving *f*(*n*) − *g*(*n*) = 0, however, the analytical result in this case isn't pretty as you're mixing a polynomial with a logarithm function. I'd just try out a few values and see where the result flips from positive to negative. Once you have one positive and one negative point you can use bisection to narrow it down.

The brute-force way would be to simply try out all *n* up to a certain point. You already know that O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) algorithms aren't suitable for large datasets, so the *n* has to be quite small. For my testing it looked like this:

```
PS Home:\> function lb($n){[math]::Log($n)/[math]::Log(2)}  # binary logarithm
PS Home:\> 1..80 | %{,($_,(8*$_*$_),(64*$_*(lb $_)))} | %{"{0}: delta={3}, I={1}, M={2}" -f $_[0],$_[1],$_[2],($_[2]-$_[1])}
...
38: delta=1210,9597126948, I=11552, M=12762,9597126948
39: delta=1024,36393828017, I=12168, M=13192,3639382802
40: delta=824,135922911648, I=12800, M=13624,1359229116
41: delta=610,216460117852, I=13448, M=14058,2164601179
42: delta=382,549232429308, I=14112, M=14494,5492324293
43: delta=141,080604940173, I=14792, M=14933,0806049402
44: delta=−114,240561917371, I=15488, M=15373,7594380826
45: delta=−383,463082570537, I=16200, M=15816,5369174295
46: delta=−666,633601368154, I=16928, M=16261,3663986318
47: delta=−963,796734153668, I=17672, M=16708,2032658463
48: delta=−1274,99519778461, I=18432, M=17157,0048022154
...
```

(Excuse the horrible code; this was just a very quick doodle.)

Comment: Why did You assume log of base 2?

Comment: The logarithm doesn't really matter, as he showed the technique in use (use both in a single equation).

Comment: @Rekin: Merge sort divides the list into *two* sublists, sorting them individually and then merging them. Which logarithm base would be more appropriate in your eyes?

Comment: @Hamish: Wrong reasons, kinda. Yes, for talking about complexity classes it's useless to give a specific base, since constant factors are ignored, but in this case we're talking actual performance data (exact numbers of steps). While those follow the complexity class they still have some more detail and to answer the question at hand we actually *need* to use the correct logarithm – in this case base 2, but that's not because of binary representation of numbers but rather an artifact of how Mergesort works.

Comment: Joey, if you look at the forest, you will tend to give one explanation, and if you look at the trees, you will tend to give another reason.

Comment: *blinks* and now you got me confused. I was merely noting that the reasons you cite here for the necessity of the binary logarithm has nothing to do with how computers store numbers or even with Landau notation.

Comment: @Hamish: If you read the link you posted it pretty clearly says that the _algorithm_ brings about the log base two, and doesn't mention the binary representation of numbers at all.

Answer (score 6):

Is there some value of n where the two are equal?

What happens above that point? Below?

Answer (score 1):

For n · 43, 8n2 · 64n log n and insertion sort beats merge sort
Although merge sort runs in £(n log n) worst-case time and insertion sort runs in £(n2) worst-case
time, the constant factors in insertion sort make it faster for small n. Therefore, it makes sense to use
insertion sort within merge sort when subproblems become sufficiently small. Consider a modification
of merge sort in which subarrays of size k or less (for some k) are not divided further, but sorted
explicitly with Insertion sort.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the equation `8n² < 64n lg n`, we arrive in the equation `2^(n/8) - n < 0`.

Once I was not in a test, just doing some exercises, i used a tool to see the graph of `f(n) = 2^(n/8) - n`.

As questioned here, there is no natural number of `n` where insertion sort have the same time as the merge sort, and, for `f(n) < 0`, we got:

> 2 <= n <= 43.

I hope it to help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this not an algebraic inequality, there isn't an analytical way to find a solution for `n` in

```
(1)   8n² < 64n log_2 (n)
```

so you need to approximate it. There are many numerical methods to do it, so we will do it using a quick Python script.

First, note that Python's `math.log` function is the logarithm to base `e`, so first you need to translate your original logarithm to base `2` into a logarithm to base `e` using the identity

```
(2)   log_2 (n) = log_e (n) / log_e (2)
```

([Proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Change_of_Base_of_Logarithm).)

Using (2) in (1) and simplifying yields

```
(3)   n / log_e (n) <= 8 / log_e (2)
```

Finally, evaluating `n` on (3) in the script

```
from math import log as ln

n = 2 # Since f(n) = n/ln (n) is not defined for n < 2.

while (n/ln (n) <= 8/ln (2)):
    n += 1

print (n)
```

outputs `n = 44`, which means that `44` is the smallest value that **does not** satisfy (1). Therefore, `n <= 43` is the condition that satisfies (1), it is to say, insertion sorts beats merge sort while the array to be sorted has, at most, `43` elements.